# extraer registro de base de datos por bloques

Tags: php

Tengo una tabla en una BD y quiero extraer de ella registros de 10 en 10 para almacenar una imágenes y no tener problemas de memoria. Estoy trabajando con laravel

El código que uso es:

```
$imagenes = new Collection();
DB::table('inscripciones')->orderBy('id')->chunk(10, function ($inscripciones) 
{
   foreach ($inscripciones as $inscripcion)
        {
            $imagenes->push($inscripcion->foto);
            $imagenes->push($inscripcion->scan_pasaporte);
        };
 });
```

Pero da un error: Me dice que `$imagenes` no está definido.
Se puede solucionar metiendo la definición `($imagenes = new Collection();)` dentro del foreach, pero claro, el resultado no es el deseado.

¿Alguna forma de que `$imagenes` tenga validez dentro de la función?

Siento si no lo explico muy bien. Gracias

Comment: Nunca he trabajado con Laravel, pero creo que seria suficiente con que declares tu variable dentro del contexto de tu consulta, es decir antes del foreach.

Comment: Lo estoy probando y parece que funciona. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Prueba pasando la variable `$imagenes` a la función anónima usando `use` (*en tu caso es necesario usar el `&` para pasarla por referencia*)

Algo así:

```
$imagenes = new Collection();
DB::table('inscripciones')->orderBy('id')->chunk(10, function ($inscripciones) use (&$imagenes) 
{
...
```

Te dejo el link de la documentación oficial: http://php.net/manual/es/functions.anonymous.php